# enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart prints "Chance" to console in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, loops, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart and this method constantly prints the word "Chance" to my console.  Is there any way to suppress this?  Whats the deal?

```
self.gameScene.physicsWorld.enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart(self.rayStart, end: self.rayEnd, usingBlock: {
    body, point, normal, stop in

})
```

Comment: Do you have the string "Chance" elsewhere in your program?

Comment: no.. i'm not printing to the console anywhere in my app

Comment: I asked this same question and deleted it because people thought it was something I was doing! Yes this is a bug I hope Apple fixes because in my case it was causing performance issues because of all the printlns!

Comment: people really need to try this for themselves =/

Answer (score 5):

I have the same "problem". It seems to be a debug output in /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit. <strike>Hopefully it will be removed in beta7.</strike>

Edit by gfrs: Not removed. Currently exists in Xcode 6 GM.

Edit 2 by gfrs: Still not fixed. Currently exists in Xcode 6.1

Comment: Have you [reported this bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) to Apple? It's unlikely to get fixed if it's not reported.

Comment: Reported, the id of this bug is 17901339.

Comment: Still not fixed in 6.3.

Comment: I have the same problem. Not fixed in 6.4.

Comment: I'm now using Xcode 7 and still getting this bug. Please tell me everyone else still sees it? I just started working on a game yesterday and it's making it nearly impossible to debug. I've googled so much and barely found any info on the bug either.. I would think for a year+ old bug there would be more reports all over the internet?